# How do I remove Plex?

Tags: applications

Hard to know which category to post this in..

Loving Elementary but want to tweak it further.

It seems to have Plex built in and I want to remove it but plex doesn't show in the repo's at all. I installed Synaptic to see if it would appear there - no joy.

So the short question is how do I remove it?

Thanks in advance.

Anthony

Comment: I have a basically clean install of 0.3.2 freya and i don't see plex anyplace. How do you know that plex is installed? what version of Elementary do you have installed? ( cmd: more /etc/*-release ).

Answer (score 1):

I've installed elementary many times and always had to install plex manually, but there is an easy way to remove it. First identify a file from plex, any file that is installed with plex would work. If you know where plex is installed his is easy, otherwise you may need to use find. [Here is a good tutorial on find](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-find-command-examples/)

Once you have the name run dpkg -S file to determin the name of the package that installed plex. For example:

```
dpkg -S /bin/cp
coreutils: /bin/cp
```

coreutils is the package that installed cp. So to remove it I'd run

```
sudo dpkg -r coreutils
```

Obviously, you don't want to remove coreutils, just whatever package installed plex.

This method will only work if plex was installed from a package. It won't work if plex was built from source.